# How do I #define an array in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is the following syntax to define an array valid syntax in C?

```
#define array[] { \
for (j=0; j<N_frequencysteps;j++)  \
{ \
array[j] = (function); \
} \
}
```

If not, how do I define an array in C?

Comment: @user442836 - did you try compiling it?  The quick answer is no, that isn't valid syntax.

Comment: I think SO doesn't like me rolling back mistakes.

Comment: Can you describe what you are calling an array? Maybe in n comparison to another language?

Comment: For an overview of defining, initializing, and using arrays, see http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-arrays.html.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you define '*valid syntax*'.

- The C pre-processor will accept it as an object-like macro.
- The C compiler will not accept the output as legitimate C.

Consider an invocation:

```
array[23];
```

The C compiler sees:

```
[] { for (j=0; j<N_frequencysteps;j++) { array[j] = (function); } } [23];
```

That is gibberish (even with the 'enter code here' removed).

---

How can you define an array in C?

```
enum { ARRAYSIZE = 23 };
int array[ARRAYSIZE];
int j;

for (j = 0; j < ARRAYSIZE; j++)
    array[j] = 0;
```

You could also use an initializer, but you might get compiler warnings unless you are thorough:

```
int array[ARRAYSIZE] = { 0 };
```

---

One more possibility: if you want to define an array and initialize it with calls to a specific function, then you could, I suppose, try:

```
#define ARRAY(type, name, size, initializer) type name[size]; \
          for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) name[j] = initializer
```

This could be used as:

```
ARRAY(int, array, 23, j % 9);
```

(Note that this initializer depends on an implementation detail of the macro - not a good idea.  But I don't think I'd ever use such a macro, anyway.)  It depends on you being in C99 mode if you have more than one of these in a particular block of code (since it would then mix code with declarations) - and also because the declaration in the `for` loop is only supported in C++ and C99, not in C90.

Comment: +1.  My preprocessor says `warning: missing whitespace after the macro name`, which at least is a hint that it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Carl: the whole thing is horrid - and yes, it is customary (but not mandatory) to put a space after the name of an object-like macro such as this `array` macro.  And the space then emphasizes how horrid it is.

Answer (score 2):

This looks really wrong. Why not define array in a normal way?

```
int array[SIZE];
for (j=0; j<N_frequencysteps;j++)
{  
   array[j] = (function);
}
```

Comment: The '(function)' notation could only be a way of assigning a pointer to function to an array of pointers to functions, assuming 'function' is in fact the name of a function.  And presumably the N_frequencysteps should be SIZE or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, SIZE should be larger than or equal to N_frequencysteps