# Filling an array in preprocessing

Tags: arrays, c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to fill an array with a constant amount of values in preprocessing.
This is to be able to MACRO these values in and reduce operations while running.

I believe this should be possible be I'm not certain.

My first approach:

```
const float Array[] = { (float)(SIZE - 0) / (float)SIZE, (float)(SIZE - 1) / (float)SIZE };
```

Although this works I believe it to be a bad solution since for every SIZE, a new value needs to be manually put in the Array.

Seconds approach where I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671900/how-do-i-define-an-array-in-c):

```
#define Array(float, Array, SIZE, i) float Array[SIZE]; \
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) Array[i] = ( (float)(SIZE - i) / (float)SIZE )
```

Although this seems like a much better approach, when I try to call `Array` it returns an error

```
identifier "Array" is undefined.
```

Is there a cleaner way than my first appoach?

EDIT:
Thanks for the responses, I made the mistake of thinking an array with `n` being variable in `Array[n]` can be non-variable/replaced by a macro. When part of the call of `Array[n]` being variable, makes the array also variable.
Conclusion:
I will just make and fill the array in runtime, using a function.

Comment: Please check for typos, the only place "array" occurs is in the error message, which is unlikely. (Note the lower case "a".) Please double check and make a [mre].

Comment: `float` is a reserved keyword and `Array` is the name of the function macro itself, you can not reuse its name, try with `#define Array(type, name, SIZE, i)`, and I don't understand what are you trying to do with `(float)(SIZE - i) / (float)`, do you mean `(float)(SIZE - i) / sizeof(float))`?

Comment: There is a missing part and missing parentheses in `( (float)(SIZE - i) / (float) )` it should be `( (float)((SIZE) - i) / (float)(SIZE) )`

Comment: @Yunnosch That was a typo in this post, that wasn't the issue in my program, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: although it is very confusing, there is no ambiguity in this macro because 1) `Array` in the macro expansion is replaced before further macro rescanning and 2) `Array` in the expansion is never followed by a `(`.

Comment: Are you going to invoke the macro `Array()` with an integer constant for the `SIZE` argument, such as `2` or `16`? What is the maximum value?

Comment: @chqrlie Im trying to make ```Array[SIZE]``` and filling all values in this array in preprocessing. So in a sense it is macro array.

Comment: Sorry, but preprocessor doesn't have loops. You will have to unroll it anyway. Do you intent to use the macro in static variable initialiazation? If not, guessing from the second call, then why not just write a normal function? `when I try to call Array` How do you "try to call Array"? From where? How did you use it?

Comment: @chqrlie oops, you are right!

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, use the Array as a static macro. I would rather not use a function or another method runtime solution to reduce runtime, since these values in ```Array``` can be determined before runtime. I figured it might be possible to do them in compile-time, since ```SIZE``` is most likely 5. With calling I mean ```Array[0] * var``` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a kind of `FORLOOP` macro, this one will use `,` as a separator and call a function count times with increasing argument depending on the count passed to it. Then create a callback function to pass to `FORLOOP` that initializes a single element and glue it together with another macro. It could look like this:

```
#define FORLOOP_1(func, priv)  func(0, priv)
#define FORLOOP_2(func, priv)  FORLOOP_1(func, priv),func(1, priv)
#define FORLOOP_3(func, priv)  FORLOOP_2(func, priv),func(2, priv)
#define FORLOOP_4(func, priv)  FORLOOP_3(func, priv),func(3, priv)
// add more...
#define FORLOOP_IN(func, priv, count)  FORLOOP_##count(func, priv)
// extra expansion wave to expand count argument
#define FORLOOP(func, priv, count)     FORLOOP_IN(func, priv, count)

// Callback to call from FORLOOP, context is SIZE
#define ARRAY_INIT_CB(idx, size)  ((float)(size - idx) / (float)size)
// Pass SIZE as context and expand up to SIZE
#define ARRAY_INIT(size)    FORLOOP(ARRAY_INIT_CB, size, size)

const float Array[] = { ARRAY_INIT(3) };
/* expands to:
const float Array[] = {
    ((float)(3 - 0) / (float)3),
    ((float)(3 - 1) / (float)3),
    ((float)(3 - 2) / (float)3)
};
*/
```

@edit Renamed `FOREACH` to `FORLOOP`, as usually `FOREACH` is doing something for each argument, and here for me [forloop](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4-1.4.15/html_node/Forloop.html) is better name as it iterates up to some count.

Comment: Yes, supportive macros like that I had in mind. +1. It'd still be a good idea to generate at least *those* with an outside script. :)

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the typo in your second approach, your second approach *will* (most likely) generate runtime code (or is at least unsuitable for filling a static/filescope array).

If you want to prefill a static array without generating runtime code, then you need to go with your first approach and generate:

```
{ (float)(SIZE - 0) / SIZE, (float)(SIZE - 1) / SIZE }
```

(the second cast is pointless) for each given `SIZE`.

While it is possible to do this succinctly with macros once you have some supportive macros for counted iterations, without those supportive macros (and those will get lengthy if your want to support large counts), a script (or perhaps a C program) outputting the initializer for a given `SIZE` is probably your best bet.

You can then either paste the result of such a script into your source code or set up your build system to generate the whole c file and then let the compiler pick it up from there.